# ¿Por qué no se abre pdf de jasper reports?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio de gestión, con Java, en Eclipse y utilizando Jaspersoft Studio. Los datos para los informes los obtengo de listas, no de bases de datos. Los genero así:

```
String outputFile="Informe.pdf";

ArrayList<DatoInforme> listaInforme=new ArrayList<>();
for(Dato p: lista) {
listaInforme.add(new DatoInforme(p.getNum(),p.getId(),p.getP()));
}

//Ordenación por 3 criterios 
Collections.sort(listaInforme,DatoInforme.comparator);


JRBeanCollectionDataSource itemsJRBean= new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaInforme);

Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
parameters.put("ColeccionBeans",itemsJRBean);
parameters.put("nombre",nombre);

InputStream input=this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/JasperReport_A4.jrxml");;
    
    try {
        JasperDesign jasperDesign= JRXmlLoader.load(input);
        JasperReport jasperReport= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        
        JasperPrint jasperPrint= JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Generando informe");

        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);
    } catch (JRException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

En principio me mostraba el informe con el Jasper Viewer y lo podía guardar en diversos formatos. Ahora también, pero en formato pdf no me funciona después al abrirlo (los demás sí). El adobe me dice que "*no es un tipo de archivo admitido o está dañado*", en cambio si utilizo impresora pdf sí lo imprime bien y se puede ver después.

Me indica este error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/SplitCharacter
at net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.classic.ClassicPdfProducerFactory.createProducer(ClassicPdfProducerFactory.java:44)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.createPdfProducer(JRPdfExporter.java:810)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.initExport(JRPdfExporter.java:706)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:667)
at net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRPdfSaveContributor.save(JRPdfSaveContributor.java:113)
at net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerToolbar.btnSaveActionPerformed(JRViewerToolbar.java:422)
at net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerToolbar$1.actionPerformed(JRViewerToolbar.java:138)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6614)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4548)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.SplitCharacter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 43 more
```

La versión de JasperReports que utilizo es la 6.19.0.

Comment: ¿Tenés la librería que te señala en el stacktrace?

Comment: Por favor, ¿a qué te refieres? Tengo jasperreports-6.19.0.jar en el classpath. Me dice al principio "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/SplitCharacter" pero no se como solucionarlo

Comment: Por eso justamente, cada biblioteca (que solemos llamar _librería_) tiene [dependencias](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.19.0). ¿Tenés todas las dependencias de ese jar que mencionaste?

Comment: No lo se, ¿cómo puedo comprobarlo? He añadido también la itext 2.1.7 pero ahora el error ha cambiado a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException" Veo que siempre son excepciones de com/lowagie pero no se como comprobar lo que me comentas.

Comment: Revisá el enlace que te proporcioné: esa no es la versión (en teoría) que necesitás de iText.

Comment: Sí, acabo de encontrar y descargar la versión de iText 2.1.7.js9, la he agregado y el error se ha solucionado. Llevaba semanas con este error sin solucionar, te lo agradezco mucho!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como se mencionó en [este comentario](/questions/605872?noredirect=1#comment1069318_605872), se está utilizando el jar de Jasper Reports en la versión *6.19.0*. Si se revisan sus [dependencias](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.19.0), se puede encontrar que *com.lowagie* hace referencia a [iText](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext).
Según el listado de dependencias de Jasper Reports en la versión mencionada previamente, la versión a utilizar de iText es la [*2.1.7.js9*](https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/ui/native/jaspersoft-repo/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js9/). Basta con agregar esta dependencia para que desaparezca el error.